# How to get "N" from $k=\log_2(N)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I know it's a easy question but unfortunately I forgot some school stuff:

I have $k=\log_2(N)$ and want to know $N$.

Is it $N=2^k$ while using $2$ as base?

Short comments are welcome :)

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Change it to an answer, so I can check it :)

Comment: I edited to remove the tag "calculus", because I feel "algebra-precalculus" is where this belongs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. More generally, if $k = \log_b(N)$ then $N = b^{\log_b(N)} = b^k$.